# can't run brew on OS X 10.9.2

Tags: ruby, osx-mavericks, homebrew

I'm trying to install RoR via Homebrew on Mac OS X Mavericks, whenever I try to run `brew` command I get this:

```
phara-mac:local pharasim$ brew doctor
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:108:in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:108:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

I've tried adding `#encoding: utf-8` on top of global.rb but it doesn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Homebrew?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had this problem before, though not with brew. If I recall correctly, I had some illegal characters in my path, and I fixed it by rewriting my `.bashrc`.

Trying running `echo $PATH` and look for any strange characters, and make sure your profiles aren't broken in any way. (like `.bashrc` or `bash_profile`).

Comment: Ha! Turns out I had `/usr/local/bin??n’export` at the end of my PATH variable. Removed it, works like a charm.